# Reccurence Relation for columns of Pascal's triangle

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

I am given the recurrence equation $$F_k(n) = \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1}(-1)^j\binom{k}{j + 1}F_k(n - j - 1)$$ and asked to solve it.  Here k is a positive integer and $F_k(k - 1) = 1$ and $F_k(n) = 0$, $n < k -1$ I have a conjecture that the solution is $$F_k(n) = \frac{(n-(k - 2))^{\underline{k - 1}}}{(k - 1)!}$$ and have tried to prove it by induction but I get stuck.  I know this works because these values are the diagonals on pascal's triangle but I am not sure how to finish the induction proof for the solving of the recurrence.

Comment: I see this now, but I’m curious what to do with the $x^k$ in the numerator

Comment: $x^{k-1}$ err on my part

Answer (score 2):

The result can be derived using generating functions. The recurrence can be written as
$$F_k(n)=\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}F_k(n-j)$$
(for a bit nicer look) and is valid for $n\geqslant k$. Now suppose $k$ is fixed, and let $F(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}F_k(n)x^n$. Then, multiplying the recurrence by $x^n$ and summing over $n\geqslant k$, you find
\begin{align}
F(x)-x^{k-1}&=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}F_k(n-j)\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}x^j\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}F_k(n-j)x^{n-j}\\&=F(x)\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}x^j\\&=F(x)\big(1-(1-x)^k\big),
\end{align}
i.e. $F(x)=x^{k-1}/(1-x)^k$. The power series for this is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases), or can be obtained from $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^k}=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right].$$

Comment: what do we make of the $x^{k - 1}$ in the numerator; also I truly appreciate the help

Comment: okay this makes sense but it leaves us with $F_k(n) = \binom{n + k -1}{k - 1}$ but from wiki $F_k(n) = \binom{n + k - 1}{k}$

Comment: $$\frac{\color{blue}{x^{k-1}}}{(1-x)^k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}x^{n\color{blue}{+k-1}}=\sum_{n=k-1}^{\infty}\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k-1}}x^n.$$